# Is it valid to redefine quote?

Tags: scheme, quote

I could redefine quote like this `(define quote display)`, such that `'"Hello!"` prints `Hello`. `quote` is a special form. I would like to know whether or not such a redefinition of a special form is allowed in Scheme. Is it valid to redefine `quote`?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, and it is allowed, but you should be very careful because it will hose everything else that depends on the standard behavior.

Comment: You should be able to change the syntax. Quote is syntax, not procedure.  If you say (define quote something), this is rewritten and executed as (define ' something), etc.  I think, it depends on the implementation.